# How to get a reference height or width of an image in the console

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying hard to reference the width of an image all to no avail. Let's say I set an image height to be 375.0. Ordinarily, the width adjust itself by default based on the set height. Please, how can i be able to print the corresponding width which wasn't specified to the console?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a GlobalKey to the image. Then you can pass the key and the context to the following function:

```dart
Size getSize(GlobalKey _key, BuildContext context) {
  final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  final boxSize = renderBox.size;
  return boxSize;
}
```

Comment: please can you give like an axample how to go about this. How do I provide a GlobalKey to the image: Image.network(
              'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/portrait-handsome-man-smiling-against-260nw-764366404.jpg',
              height: 375.0),

Comment: `GlobalKey myKey = GlobalKey();` and then you add to your image widget `key: myKey`